# Upgrading turtlebot to electric

Tags: turtlebot, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I have a turtlebot that I am trying to upgrade to electric so that I can use the turtlebot arm, and I am wondering if there is any info on how to go about doing that.  I have installed electric on it experimentally, but do I need to go through reinstalling all the turtlebot software?  Does the entire OS need to be reinstalled?  I saw the turotial pages for upgrading turtlebot to electric, but they appear to be mostly missing and claim that the iso on the page is not correct yet.  Thank you very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11554/upgrading-turtlebot-to-electric/) by [Aroarus](https://answers.ros.org/users/990/aroarus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2011-10-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A re-install is not needed. I've filled in the [upgrade tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot/electric/Robot%20Upgrade). Please let us know if you have any issues.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [patrick_hammer](https://answers.ros.org/users/465/patrick_hammer/) on 2012-01-23**:
What does upstart do?